# Why does the pipe operator work?

Tags: f#

If the pipe operator is created like this:

```
let (|>) f g = g f
```

And used like this:

```
let result = [2;4;6] |> List.map (fun x -> x * x * x)
```

Then what it seems to do is take List.Map and puts it behind (fun x -> x * x * x)
And doesn't change anything about the position of [2;4;6]

So now it looks like this:

```
let result2 = [2;4;6] (fun x -> x * x * x) List.map
```

However this doesn't work.

I am just learning f# for the first time now. And this bothered me while reading a book about f#. So I might learn what I'm missing later but I decided to ask anyway.

It is obvious though that I am missing something major. Since I can easily recreate the pipe operator. But I don't get why it works. I might embarrass myself very soon as I learn more. Oh well.

Comment: the operator is infix not prefix - you are applying it to the wrong things

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The pipe operator is simply syntactic sugar for chained method calls.  It's very similar to how linq expressions are expressed in C#.

Explanation from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/05/09/f-in-20-minutes-part-ii.aspx):

Forward Pipe Operator
I love this guy. The Forward pipe operator is simply defined as:

```
let (|>) x f = f x
```

And has a type signature:

```
'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b
```

Which translates to: given a generic type 'a, and a function which takes an 'a and returns a 'b, then return the application of the function on the input.

Rather than explaining this, let me give you an example of where it can be used:

```
// Take a number, square it, then convert it to a string, then reverse that string
let square x         = x * x
let toStr (x : int)  = x.ToString()
let rev   (x : string) = new String(Array.rev (x.ToCharArray()))

// 512 -> 1024 -> "1024" -> "4201"
let result = rev (toStr (square 512))
```

The code is very straight forward, but notice just how unruly the syntax looks. All we want to do is take the result of one computation and pass that to the next computation. We could rewrite it by introducing a series of new variables:

```
let step1 = square 512
let step2 = toStr step1
let step3 = rev step2
let result = step3
```

But now you need to keep all those temporary variables straight.  What the (|>) operator does is take a value, and 'forward it' to a function, essentially allowing you to specify the parameter of a function before the function call. This dramatically simplifies F# code by allowing you to pipe functions together, where the result of one is passed into the next. So to use the same example the code can be written clearly as:

```
let result = 512 |> square |> toStr |> rev
```

**Edit**:

In F# what you're really doing with a method call is taking a function and then applying it to the parameter that follows, so in your example it would be `List.map (fun x -> x * x * x)` is applied to `[2;4;6]`.  All that the pipe operator does is take the parameters in reverse order and then do the application reversing them back.

function: `List.map (fun x -> x * x * x)`
parameter: `[2;4;6]`

Standard F# call syntax: f g

Reversed F# call syntax: g f

Standard:

```
let var = List.map (fun x -> x * x * x) [2;4;6]
```

Reversed:

```
let var = [2;4;6] |> List.map (fun x -> x * x * x)
```

Comment: I know its syntactic sugar and I created it right there in the code above. I am now asking why this function works: let (|>) f g = g f - or how it works differently than I understand it as I wrote in my question.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info you put in. Are these the 2 functions going into the pipe forward operator?: List.map (fun x -> x * x * x) - Because like I showed in my post, reordering those 2 doesn't work.

Comment: Ahh I'm starting to get it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I see where you're getting tripped up.  `List.map` is a curried function that return a function and takes two parameters: a function and a list.  `List.map (fun x -> x * x * x)` returns a new method which only takes a list.  So in your example you're applying the function returned from the call of `List.map (fun x -> x * x * x)` to your list.

Comment: Whilst this is a nice example, I'm puzzled as to why no one has pointed out in the last four years that `square 512` is `262144`, not `1024`.

Comment: @DavidArno that's a good question.  Now do I change it to make it more correct or leave it because its amusing?

Comment: I'd leave it. As you say, it's amusing and doesn't detract from the fact that it's still a good answer.

Answer (score 8):

The brackets around `|>` mean it is an infix operator so your example could be written

```
let result = (|>) [2;4;6] (List.map (fun x -> x * x * x))
```

Since `|>` applies its first argument to the second, this is equivalent to

```
let result = (List.map (fun x -> x * x)) [2;4;6]
```

Comment: The brackets themselves do not make it an infix operator. Adding brackets (parens, actually) when _using_ it turn it into a function, as opposed to an operator. Upon definition they're required for both infix and prefix operators.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said above, basically you're misunderstanding what result2 would resolve to. It would actually resolve to

`List.map (fun x -> x * x * x) [2;4;6]`

List.map takes two arguments: a function to apply to all elements in a list and a list.  `(fun x -> x * x * x)` is the first argument and `[2;4;6]` is the second.

Basically just put what's on the left of `|>` after the end of what's on the right.

Comment: Nice that you were more explicit about argument order, with the "... after the end"... Anyone coming to F# late in the game having seen Elixir's `|>` first will definitely be tripped up, since that applies the value on the left as the _first_ argument.

Answer (score 3):

If you enter your definition of `|>` into fsi and look at the operator's signature derived by type inference you'll notice `val ( |> ) : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b`, i.e. argument `'a` being given to function `('a -> 'b)` yields `'b`.

Now project this signature onto your expression `[2;4;6] |> List.map (fun x -> x * x * x)` and you'll get `List.map (fun x -> x * x * x) [2;4;6]`, where the argument is list `[2;4;6]` and the function is [partially applied](http://www.uncarved.com/blog/not_currying.mrk) function of one argument `List.map (fun x -> x * x * x)`.